# Create a desktop icon for a Tkinter script

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, desktop, shortcut

I have written a python script with a Tkinter GUI. I would like to create a desktop icon that will execute this script so that the end-user (not myself) will be able to double-click the icon and have the GUI load, rather than 'run' the script from the terminal or python shell and then have to F5 from there.

Is there a way to do this? I have googled many arrangements of my question but most answers seem to be normal python scripts, not ones which are Tkinter based.

I am using a Raspberry Pi with Wheezy and Python 2.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS are you wanting to run this on?

Comment: Well that's a good point. I want to run it on a Raspberry Pi. Added info in question

Comment: I notice that someone has downvoted my question but did not explain why. A more helpful person would have commented with the reason so that I do not make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create executables(icons that I click to start the programs I write) using 'py2exe'. I use windows 7 and I am not sure if it would work for you with Raspberry Pi, but a google search may clear that up for you. I will provide the link below. Basically you end up with a folder with the executable(icon) and also some files, without which the executable won't work. It's unfortunate that you get this extra 'baggage', but it's still handy and the best solution I have come across. I don't think there is a much better way, but I am not 100% on that. Interestingly, I found that you could delete most of these baggage files and the executable would still work, it was trial and error, but it didn't take long. If I want to send the folder to someone, I zip it first.

[py2exe is here](http://www.py2exe.org/)

If you need a 64 bit binary you can get it here, along with, actually, pretty much every other version. [get py2exe here also](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#py2exe)

Comment: Thank you for this. I googled py2exe for Linux and found pyinstaller and Freeze, which looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Besides creating executable file other option is create simple .bat file:

1. Open notepad
2. Enter "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Your ID\script.py"
   First part is path to python.exe, second to your python script
3. save file as .bat file, ex. "open_program.bat"

Now simply double click on saved .bat file icon should open your script.

Answer (score 0):

I like using [cx-freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) to convert python scripts to `exe`.

There is very easy to follow documentation to do this. In short, you create a `setup.py` script that specifies what libraries and packages you want to include or exclude in your application.

You can then run the build in the console and it will create a build folder, in which will be an `Application File`. You can create a Desktop short cut using `send to` and selecting desktop.

[Documentation link](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the script as a .pyw file so the user can click on the file and the GUi would open